# Animate a partial page turn with a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, uipageviewcontroller

Does anyone know how to animate a partial page turn with a `UIPageViewController`.  I would like to suggest to the user that he can turn the page by showing a partial page turn when the user sees the first page for the first time.  Can someone please tell me how to do this with Swift code?

Comment: Well there really isn't a good way. Can't you just put up a label or graphic telling the user that this is possible? Show them a video of it, even.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Matt.  I will show a message box saying they can answer the question and then flip to the next page to answer the next.